# Error message for data duplication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, duplicate-data

I have tried this below code, but it throws a unique key constraint error. I would like it as a pop-up message; see my below code.

```
using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    var fromdate = DateTime.Parse(txtfromdate.Text);
    var todate = DateTime.Parse(txttodate.Text);
    var datedif1 = (todate - fromdate).Days;

    var sqlInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO datelist ([datedif],[batch],[daywk],[semester],[weekbatch],[subject],[facultyname],[facultyid],[WeekMonth])  VALUES  (@datedif,@batch,@daywk,@semester,@weekbatch,@subject,@facultyname,@facultyid,@weekMonth)", con2);
    var sqlParamater = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@datedif", SqlDbType.Date);
    var sqlParameter1 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@batch", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sqlParameter2 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@daywk", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sqlParameter3 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@semester", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sqlParameter4 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@weekbatch", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sqlParameter5 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sqlParameter6 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@facultyname", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sqlParameter7 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@facultyid", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var sqlParameter8 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@WeekMonth", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    con2.Open();
    try
    { 
        for (var i = 0; i <= datedif1; i++)
        {
            var consecutiveDate = fromdate.AddDays(i);

            sqlParamater.Value = consecutiveDate;
            sqlParameter1.Value = batch1;
            sqlParameter2.Value = dayweek;
            sqlParameter3.Value = semester;
            sqlParameter4.Value = weekbatch;
            sqlParameter5.Value = subject;
            sqlParameter6.Value = faculty;
            sqlParameter7.Value = facultyid;
            sqlParameter8.Value = weekmonth;

            int s = sqlInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con2.Close();
    }
    catch(ConstraintException ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("data are duplicated");
    }
}
```

Here's a screen shot of the error which am getting,

[image]

Comment: How about not throwing the exception but handling it yourself and showing it as a popup? The system doesn't know what you want unless you do it yourself.

Comment: In try block it is inserting the values and in catch block it should show me an error data a;ready inserted.This is what i did in these code but is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199513/try-catch-does-not-catch     catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

Comment: @Vinay not going to work, considering this is a web application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199513/try-catch-does-not-catch     Edited: catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Have your pop up logic with ex.ToString();//MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}@Brendan Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching a [`ConstraintException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.constraintexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but the insert is throwing a [`SqlException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is not a subclass of `ConstraintException`. Change the catch and you will get it handled.